# Is it possible to bold an NSString?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsstring

Is it possible to make an NSString bold? If so, how? I am not using UILabel or UIIextView for some reason.

Comment: How are you displaying the string?

Comment: i display it with another string, with method stringByAppendingString, but just first string that i want to be bold, and normal for another string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSStrings hold strings and no text formatting. I assume you could render an NSString using webkit; in that case the NSString will hold html content...

Comment: render NSString using webkit.?? i dont understand, iam sorry,, would u like to explain that clearly.??

Comment: I'm assuming you have a string @"Hello World" and you need a part of the string Bold. NSStrings have no capability to display themselves so you need code or a control to render the string or use a bit of code. Have webkist to render a string like @"Hello <b>World</b>"

Comment: One could also use an NSAttributedString instead of an NSString, and use Core Text to display it.

Comment: Note that NSAttributedString is only available in >4.0