# Bold symbols in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

How can I make **Bold (strong)** the first 3 symbols of a `NSString`? For example I have string `@"Hello"`, but I need: **Hel**lo

I have this string:

```
NSString *testString = @"Hello";
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6013751/6619234

Comment: Use `NSAttributeString`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to bold part of a NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013705/any-way-to-bold-part-of-a-nsstring)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to bold an NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829469/is-it-possible-to-bold-an-nsstring)

Answer (score 1):

You will be use this method, in which add your original string and part of string in which you want change its font.

This is global solution for format a current string.

Syntax for Calling the method

```
[self getAttributedStringWithFullString:@"Hello" forRangeOfString:@"Hel" withRangeOfStringFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f]];





-(NSAttributedString*)getAttributedStringWithFullString:(NSString*)fullString
                                       forRangeOfString:(NSString*)rangeOfString
                                  withRangeOfStringFont:(UIFont*)rangeOfStringFont
{
    NSMutableAttributedString* att_string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:fullString];
    NSRange atRange = [att_string.string rangeOfString:rangeOfString];

    if (atRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [att_string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:rangeOfStringFont range:atRange];
    }

    return att_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *testString = @"Hello";

//Checking string length
if (testString.length >= 3 )
{

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:testString];

    //Bold font range
    NSRange boldFontRange = NSMakeRange(0, 3);
    [attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0] range:boldFontRange];

    //Setting Normal Font
    NSRange normalFontRange = NSMakeRange(3, testString.length - 3);
    [attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0] range:normalFontRange];


    //Setting attributed Text to Label
    [self.lblTitle setAttributedText:attrString];
}
```